# I can't get all data with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose, find, limit

I'm using Nodejs and Mongoose.
I've 134 entries on my database.
When I want to get all data from database query hasn't done.
There is no error or anything else i've got.

If I add a limit at query, data is not coming after 101st.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var customers = mongoose.model('Customer');

customers
    .find({})
    .limit(parseInt(request.body.limit, 10))
    .exec(function(err, result){
        if (err)
            response.send(err);
        response.send(result);
    });
```

PS: I'm  working on localhost and my system is Mac OSX (El Capitan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change parseInt function like

```
customers
    .find({})
    .limit(parseInt(request.body.limit, 10))
    .exec(function(err, result){
        if (err)
            response.send(err);
        response.send(result);
    });
```

where 10 indicates the base of the number you are passing to parseInt. Limit here ensures that you only get as much records as the number you pass to it.

Comment: on my code also i write 10 but some how it show 102 i guess i done mistake when i share here my question. i have change to 10

Comment: Are you able to receive data now?

Comment: When I add batchsize on search it fix the problem. thanks.